# Does the Sense HAT have an ADC?

Tags: analog-to-digital, sense-hat

I want to use analog signals with a Pi via the [Sense HAT](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/sense-hat/). Does the sense hat have an analog to digital converter (ADC)?

Comment: A link to "sense hat" would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The SenseHAT does not have any analog inputs. The ideal solution is to remove the standard GPIO header and fit an extra long, stacking one through the holes.

[image: Extra long 40-pin header]

You can then look at wiring up, for example, [an MCP3008 chip](https://www.adafruit.com/product/856) which will give you 8 analog inputs.

Comment: Removing the GPIO header from the sense hat? That's not easy, there's little space to work with.

Comment: You can just pull the female header on the underside off.

Comment: Yes, turns out it's not soldered in place. Works great :-)

Answer (score 0):

From the [specifications](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/sense-hat/) or [technical details](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2738) I think no.

The sensors used are modern and I assume digitally.

If there should be an adc it's not intended for separate use.

But you can check yourself: recent RaspBian versions come with an emulator,
or check [online](https://astro-pi.org/updates/sense-hat-emulator/)